# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to call the `confirmDialog(id)` function by passing the `id` of that button to the function and then processing upon it. But when I try to run the code I get the following error:

`user.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: confirmDialog is not defined`

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
    const list_div = document.querySelector("#list-div");

    db.collection("users").onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
        let sr_no = 1;
        let i = 0;
        querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(function (change) {
            if (change.type === "added") {
                list_div.innerHTML +=
                    "<tbody><tr><th>" + sr_no +
                    "</th><td>" + change.doc.data().name +
                    "</td><td>" + change.doc.data().email +
                    "</td><td><button class='btn btn-danger' id='" + change.doc.data().uid + "' onclick='confirmDialog(this.id)' >Delete</button></td></tr>";
                sr_no++;
                i++;
            }
        });
        list_div.innerHTML += "</tbody>";
    });

});

function confirmDialog(id) {

    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    console.log(id);

    modal.style.display = "block";
    span.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

}
```

I have defined the function but still get the error. I cannot use `getElementById()` and attach a click listener to it since I don't know the id.

Comment: You haven't told us where the code in the question is defined, but it must not be at global scope (it's within a function callback or a module or similar), which means that `confirmDialog` is not a global. `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers can only call globals. That's one of the many reasons not to use them.

Comment: Also, using `+=` on `innerHTML` is generally not good practice. `innerHTML` is not a simple string, it's an accessor property. When you do `element.innerHTML += something`, the browser has to: 1. Recurse through all child nodes of the element and its descendant elements building up an HTML string, 2. Give that string to the JavaScript code, 3. Accept the modified string back from the JS code, 4. Destroy all the previous nodes within `element` and all of its descendants, 4. Parse the HTML from the string, and 5. Build a new nested set of elements to replace the old ones. Instead,

Comment: either build up the full HTML you plan to append in a string and then use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), or build the DOM structure in memory (rather than building an HTML string) and then append it.